# Transforming nested JSON coming from Api into dataframe with Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, nested

This is Json coming from Api put into list:

```
final = [{
"email":"hildamicalay@yahoo.es"
"createdAt":"2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00" 
"statistics":{
      "clicked":[
         0:{
            "campaignId":415
            "links":[
               0:{
                  "count":1
                  "eventTime":"2019-10-17T17:29:16.551-05:00"
                 }
            ]
         }
         1:{...}
         2:{...}
         3:{...}
      ]
...
}]
```

I want to make a Dataframe with this, the desired output is:

```
count campaignId   eventTime                    email                       createdAt    status
0   1        415  2019-10-17    hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
1   1        415  2020-06-15    hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
2   1        415  2020-06-15    hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
3   1        415  2020-06-15    hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
4   2        415  2020-10-14    hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
5   1        415  2020-10-14    hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
```

What I have tried is this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.json_normalize(final,['statistics','clicked','links'],['email','createdAt'],errors='ignore')
df3['status'] = 'clicked'
```

But I only getting this. I try to get `campaignId` in dataframe, any help would be appreciated.

```
 count                      eventTime                   email                       createdAt    status
0   1   2019-10-17T17:29:16.551-05:00   hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
1   1   2020-06-15T18:27:33.179-05:00   hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
2   1   2020-06-15T18:21:32.942-05:00   hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
3   1   2020-06-15T18:22:46.963-05:00   hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
4   2   2020-10-14T18:23:18.949-05:00   hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
5   1   2020-10-14T18:25:42.373-05:00   hildamicalay@yahoo.es   2019-10-14T15:22:35.188-05:00   clicked
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
df3 = pd.json_normalize(final,['statistics','clicked'],['email','createdAt'],errors='ignore')
df3 = df3.explode('links')
df3 = pd.concat([df3 ,df3['links'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to change eventTime to date?

```
import datetime as dt
df3['eventTime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['eventTime'])
df['eventTime'] = df['eventTime'].dt.date
```

Comment: So sorry, what I try to get is campaignId in dataframe